# gradle cache issue on the task

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle

**Context:** Currently, My Application is running on the gradle 2.x in production. Now we are moving from 2.4 to **gradle 5.x**. And while I'm doing that, I'm constantly getting the below errors on the jenkins-

```
12:13:34  Invalidating in-memory cache of /opt/dops_jen/.gradle/caches/journal-1/file-access.bin
12:13:34  Caching disabled for task ':cleanDir' because:
12:13:34    Caching has not been enabled for the task
12:13:34  Task ':cleanDir' is not up-to-date because:
12:13:34    No history is available.
```

and this error is for each task present in my gradle my file and because of that the tasks are UP-TO-Date.

**My Solution:**
I have tried couple of solutions found here and gradle documentation, but none of them seems to be working, I'm still getting the above mentioned errors.

1. org.gradle.caching=true
2. gradleBuildTask=deploy --build-cache --stacktrace (on jenkins job property, deploy calls cleanDir)
3. Gradle tool team - cleaned the cache as well on server

Can any of you help me to find the correct solution.

Comment: That doesn't look like error messages to me - more like informational messages. And it specifically says that `cleanDir` is _not_ up-to-date, so it should run. If it is another task that is not running when you think it should, you probably have some inputs to that task that Gradle does know about. In that case, you have to configure the inputs. But you need to provide more information before we can help you narrow it down. Also, caching is disabled by default (as it says), and you should _not_ enable it before the build works without it.

Comment: @BjørnVester -  yes, these are more of informational messages. Nevertheless, it shouldn't be coming. This is how i take it. To answer your questions - like many other tasks, in my gradle file, cleanDir is an independent task. The deploy task calls it before it compiles the code. Wot's happening is - for every task, deploy calls, i'm getting these caching messgaes. There are no input to these tasks, they are mostly cleaning the WS, downloading the JAR files from artifactory etc etc.

Comment: But you need to provide more information => more than happy! tell me...

Comment: I apologize for being a bit thick skulled at times, but I don't understand what you are looking to do - are you asking how to suppress those informational messages, why they are there, or is there an actual problem with the build? Maybe you have caching enabled either globally or for the entire project after all, but specifically disabled for that task (which would make sense). Try disabling caching completely with `--no-build-cache`, though it might of cause make your build slower. Or running at a higher logging level (e.g. QUIET or LIFECYCLE) if there is too much output.

Comment: @BjørnVester - i would like to get rid of of these messages. Apparently, because of this, **none of the tasks are up to date**. Same task works pretty well in the lower version of the gradle, all are UP-TO-DATE. I wonder why and this is what I'm looking for. build Jenkins property is: ```gradleBuildTask=-p calypso_cdbo deploy -Dorg.gradle.daemon=false -i --project-cache-dir ./project_cache --stacktrace``` => this means  cache gets created in the project dir.